# How do you call those financial announcement from a public company which are not regular (neither annual nor quarterly, ...)

Tags: word-choice

How do you call those financial announcement from a public company which are not regular (neither annual nor quarterly, ...)

"Urgent" report? "Untime" report? "Irregular" report?

Comment: Do you have an example of such a report? Usually if a company has something to share that isn't part of the required annual or quarterly reports it releases a press statement, or [press release](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pressrelease.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You often hear of  "annual assembly" and "extraordinary assembly".
For a report, "additional" might be more appropriate.